# What are the disadvantages of using ui-router over ngRouter?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ngroute

"If you are getting some extra then..
 you must be compromising something somewhere."

UI-Router comes with many advantages and extra thing that you can get easily over ngRoute.
I am curious about the disadvantages of using UI-Router?

Comment: ngRoute is a **route provider**, uiRouter is a **state machine**.  it just happens that because states need to be navigated to, these two libraries have overlapping functionality.  Whether a state machine is better than a route provider is very subjective, and generally depends on the purpose of the app.